# How to re-arrange lists, divide one list into 2 lists with a particular step

Tags: list-manipulation

How to re-arrange following list:

```
{a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3,a4,b4} or this {a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3},{a4,b4}
```

to get:

```
{a1,a2,a3,a4},{b1,b2,b3,b4}
```

so divide a list into 2 lists of rearranging step=2, each second element

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate for the first case; simply use `Transpose` for the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
l1 = {a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4,  b4} ;
l2 = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {a4, b4}};

Transpose[ArrayReshape[#, {4, 2}]] &@l1
(* {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}} *)

Transpose[ArrayReshape[#, {4, 2}]] &@l2
(* {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}} *)
```

Also

```
Flatten[l1][[# ;; ;; 2]] & /@ {1, 2}
(* {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}}*)

Flatten[l2][[# ;; ;; 2]] & /@ {1, 2}
(* {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}} *)
```

For `l2` only:

```
Thread[l2]
(* {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}} *)

Flatten[l2, {{2}, {1}}]
(* {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {b1, b2, b3, b4}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

2nd list:

```
Transpose[{{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {a4, b4}}]
```

1st list can be transformed into the second list and then handled the same way:

```
Transpose[Partition[{a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4}, 2]]
```

It can also be done with `Part` (`[[ ]]`):

```
l1 = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {a4, b4}};
{l1[[All, 1]], l1[[All, 2]]}

l2 = {a1, b1, a2, b2, a3, b3, a4, b4};
{l2[[1 ;; ;; 2]], l2[[2 ;; ;; 2]]}
```

This is not recommended for this situation, but it's good to know :)